# HashMap with multiple keys leading to a single value

Tags: java, hashmap

Sometimes two words (or variations of a word) are mapped to the same 
response. Deal with this by mapping synonyms or related expressions to the same string so that you do not need multiple entries in the response map for the same response.

I need to avoid adding the same value twice. The keys below are created from user inputs splitted to single words. The values below are responses generated for user inputs that contain keys.

```
responseMap.put("bug", 
                    "Well, you know, all software has some bugs. But our 
software engineers\n" +
                    "are working very hard to fix them. Can you describe the 
problem a bit\n" +
                    "further?");
    responseMap.put("buggy", 
                    "Well, you know, all software has some bugs. But our 
software engineers\n" +
                    "are working very hard to fix them. Can you describe the 
problem a bit\n" +
                    "further?");
```

How can I add such "multiple" keys? In parameters  - can K be a regular expression, for example? Or should I create a HashMap where K is a certain word and V contains an arraylist of its sysnonyms, and then try to iterate over the ArrayList to compare the splitted user input with the elements in the ArrayList to extract the necessary key?

P.S. I am not a student doing this for a grade. It's just for self-education, and I don't have a teacher to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a list of synonyms.

```
List<String> synonyms = new ArrayList<String>();
synonyms.add("Bug");
synonyms.add("Buggy");

if(synonyms.contains(userInputString)){
Map.get("bug");
}
```

Create a set like this for each of your map keys... if the list is short enough to be practical. But a Map by definition should have unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Rereading this part of the instructions again *"Deal with this by mapping synonyms or related expressions to the same string"* it sounds like what the exercise *could* have in mind is performing the lookups in 2 steps.

First you have a map of all the possible synonyms to the same value e.g.

```
bug → bug
buggy → bug
mistake → bug
other → something else
etc.
```

and then a second map with the canonical keys to the responses

```
bug → "Well, you know, all software has some bugs..."
```

and so a lookup consists of checking the first map to find the key to use in the second map which will then give the response needed.